# How to remove default chrome style for select Input?

Tags: html, css

How do I remove the default yellow box border of Selected input and select fields in chrome or any browser like safari?
I want to customize input with custom box shadow css. How do I remove the default browser select border?

Comment: use background image , box shadow etc

Comment: duplicate  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920306/google-chrome-form-autofill-and-its-yellow-background

Comment: yes ,this is duplicate question , always try to search or find the solution before posting.

Comment: none of them worked and i got minus one for the question, amazing

Comment: You got a minus one because the question has already been asked and answered, plus you weren't exactly clear, you didn't show any code or what you have tried already. It wasn't my -1 btw.

Comment: what do i have to exactly show, this is amusing

Comment: and FWI it is not the duplicate one from the above question

Comment: ah but it is a duplicate of this one ;) note that you're looking for the answer I've linked, not the one that's currently marked as accepted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345897/html-select-font-size/11869370#comment44107277_11869370

Answer (score 116, accepted):

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

and add your own style

Comment: Don't worked for me. The background is not appear in styles computed of Chrome dev tools, but appear to me in the input element.

Answer (score 52):

```
textarea, input { outline: none; }
```

via https://stackoverflow.com/a/935572/1036298

Comment: All of the vendor prefixes didn't work for me. Seems `outline: none` is now the default way to handle this?

Comment: This doesn't remove the icon background image/icon

Comment: Only this Worked for me too! Thanks

Answer (score 17):

Mixin for Less

```
.appearance (@value: none) {
    -webkit-appearance:     @value;
    -moz-appearance:        @value;
    -ms-appearance:         @value;
    -o-appearance:          @value;
    appearance:             @value;
}
```

Comment: won't necessarily work without the border trick (see my comment), but aside from that why not write even less LESS (sorry;) `.appearance {-webkit-appearance: none; -moz-appearance: none; and so on }`

Comment: @henry why would you prohibit yourself the ability to set a specific value? this way a mixin is more useful. But of course, it would suffice for OP request.

Answer (score 8):

use simple code for remove default browser style for outline

```
input { outline: none; }
```

Answer (score 6):

In your CSS add this:

```
input {-webkit-appearance: none; box-shadow: none !important; }
:-webkit-autofill { color: #fff !important; }
```

*Only for Chrome!* :)

Comment: ... And Safari and Opera and all other browsers in this list http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers#WebKit-based :-)

Comment: @Julian While I wrote this answer, I was unaware of that. :) Thanks anyways. :D

Answer (score 2):

```css
input:-webkit-autofill {
    background: #fff !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about when you click on an input box, rather than just hover over it? This fixed it for me:

```
input:focus {
   outline: none;
   border: specify yours;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When looking at an input with a type of number, you'll notice the spinner buttons (up/down) on the right-hand side of the input field. These spinners aren't always desirable, thus the code below removes such styling to render an input that resembles that of an input with a type of text.

[image]

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
}
```

Comment: Can you explain this solution?

Comment: @TobiasTheel Yes, please see my revised answer.

Comment: Thanks, way better with a little explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

Before Applying Property box-shadow : none
[image: Before Applying Property box-shadow : none]

After Applying Property box-shadow : none
[image: After Applying Property box-shadow : none]

This is the easiest solution and it worked for me

```
input {
   box-shadow : none;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click input box then you can see the default style. You want to remove it and add your own style then apply below code...

Method 1:

```css
input:focus {
    outline: none;
 }
```

Method 2:

```css
input:focus, textarea:focus, select:focus{
        outline: none;
}
```

Hope you useful this...

Comment: While this may answer the question, I can't see any difference from the existing answers.